# How create dynamic json model

Tags: flutter, dart

how can I make a dynamic JSON model for this Josn,  all keys are dynamic like "Large,X-Larg, Red, Blue", only the key `optionDisplayValues` is

```
{
   "optionDisplayValues":{
      "Large":{
         "value":"Large",
         "displayType":"text"
      },
      "X-Larg":{
         "value":"X-Larg",
         "displayType":"text"
      },
      "Red":{
         "value":"#7d4141",
         "displayType":"color"
      },
      "Blue":{
         "value":"#25a953",
         "displayType":"color"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go to this [link](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/), and you can paste your `json` there.

Then after that, you can name your class whatever you want and click on the `Generate` button. It will generate the model for you.

There are also plugins available for both `Android studio` and `VS code` for converting JSON to dart.

Comment: It does not support dynamic fields, you need to write them as maps by hand

Answer (score 0):

Each dynamic item should be represented as `Map<DisplayValue>`, so:

`DisplayValue` should be:

```
class DisplayValue {
String value;
String displayText;
}
```

And your collection should be:

```
class MyDataCollection {
Map<String,DisplayValue> optionDisplayValues;
}
```

To generate `toJson` and `fromJson` method use `json_serializable` plugin:
https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable

You will also need to generate constructors and put json annotations/methods as required by that lib.